# aligning image with anchor in listitem

Tags: html, css

I have created list of links as such

```
 <ul style="font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; display: block;" class="links">
   <li>
       <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=api.jquery.com"
        style="display:inline-block;"> 
       <a href="" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; background:
       white;">.append() | jQuery API Documentation</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?
       domain=www.startutorial.com" style="display:inline-block;"> 
       <a href="" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; background: 
       white;">DropzoneJs + PHP: How to build a file upload form </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

the problem is that the `a` aligns with the bottom of the `img`. I want it to align with the top. I tried `float` but that messes the whole layout and then will have to apply the `.clearfix` hacks which does not look very nice. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vertical-align:top`

```css
a{
  vertical-align:top
    }
```

```html
<ul style="font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; display: block;" class="links">
   <li>
       <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=api.jquery.com"
        style="display:inline-block;"> 
       <a href="" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; background:
       white;">.append() | jQuery API Documentation</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?
       domain=www.startutorial.com" style="display:inline-block;"> 
       <a href="" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; background: 
       white;">DropzoneJs + PHP: How to build a file upload form </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually I was applying `vertical-align` to `list-item` .. :(

Comment: @whatever, do you mean it works better if you apply vertical-align to list-item or do you mean the answer is not working at all?

Comment: @AmmarCSE new to CSS and was just reading this here http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ , vertical align works on inline elements ? i taught it did't . i know it works on inline-block !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, interesting point, I never thought of vertical-align in terms of what type of display an element has. Guess we learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

I use `a {vertical-align: top;}`. Vertical-align works great for this type of issue.